# Is the `Monad ((,) w)` instance anywhere standard?

Tags: haskell, monads

I use the pair spelling of `Writer` all the time, but I always have to instantiate myself:

```
instance (Monoid w) => Monad ((,) w) where
    return x = (mempty, x)
    ~(w,x) >>= f = let (w', y) = f x in (w `mappend` w', y)
```

Does this live anywhere in the standard libraries?

Comment: Now that you mention it, it's rather curious that `Control.Monad.Instances` contains the `Functor` instance for `((,) a)` but not a `Monad` instance, despite having the anonymous reader `((->) e)` and anonymous error `Either e`.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211150/why-isnt-implemented-with-control-monad-instances-by-default

Comment: @McCann: How do you implement a Monad instance for `((,) a)`? For instance, I have no clue how to implement `return`.

Comment: @trinithis, just like the the one in the question (you need a `Monoid a` constraint).  This is it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As camccann mentioned in the comment, `Control.Monad.Instances` defines only the `Functor` instance.

`Control.Monad.Applicative` defines the `Applicative` instance.

The `transformers` package, and thus also version 2 and above of the
`mtl` package, define a wrapper function `writer :: (a, w) -> Writer w a`.

But I have not found the `Monad` instance anywhere.