# Why isn't (->) implemented with Control.Monad.Instances by default

Tags: haskell, monads, functor

I was reading [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids). It says I need to explicitly load `Control.Monad.Instances` to get the following syntax to work:

```
( ( fmap (+5) ) (+5) ) 4
```

Why is that? Why if functors are this underlying and unifying technology do I have to explicitly load `Control.Monad.Instances` to get that functionality. How is (->) implemented without it (or is just hidden and only `->` exported)? Why isn't the use of `fmap` over function types implemented by default?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204086/is-the-monad-w-instance-anywhere-standard

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are 3 different concepts involved here.  The function type, the Functor type class, and the Functor "instance".  The function type, (->), is built into the language and its existence and implementation are completely unrelated to Functor and fmap.  The type class is the specification of the signature of its associated methods.  The "instance" is an implementation of that signature.

So to make your question clearer, I would re-phrase it as "why isn't the Functor instance for (->) provided in the Prelude?" (the Prelude being the module that's in scope by default).  As it is currently phrased, it doesn't make a lot of sense.

The answer to the modified question is simple:  the Haskell Report (the official language specification, which is where the Prelude's interface is specified) doesn't include it.  Arguably it should, but the Haskell language and libraries have evolved a lot since then, and Haskell standards tend to change slowly.  In any case, right or wrong, that's why.

Answer (score 2):

Functor is not a language feature, it is just a useful typeclass that a random module happens to define.  To use that module's definition of Functor, you have to load it, end of story.