# Monad instance for pairs

Tags: haskell, monads

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204086/is-the-monad-w-instance-anywhere-standard) shows an instance definition for `(,) a b`, where `a` is an instance of `Monoid`.

However, I don't know how to write similar thing for `(,) a b`, and `b` is an instance of `Monoid`? I can basically do this as long as I can write the definition:

```
instance Monoid b => Monad ((,) ???) where
    return a = (a,mempty)
    ~(a,b) >>= f = let (c,b1) in f a in (c,b `mappend` b1)
```

So the question is how to write the `???` part?

**UPDATE**

Actually this question is special case of a more generic problem: is it possible to write instance of type classes that act on some types that is not appear at the end? In my case, the type constructor is `(,) a b`, and I want to make it an instance of `Monad a` where `a` is not the last type parameter.

Comment: It's also interesting to see how the homogeneous type `(a,a)` (actually one isomorphic to it) can be made a `Monad`, in totally different way as compared to `(a,b)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We could write, for now synonyms works inappropriate for this case, so we use newtype:

```
newtype RevTuple b a = RevTuple { totuple :: (a , b) }

instance Monoid b => Monad (RevTuple b) where
    return a = RevTuple (a,mempty)
    (RevTuple (a,b)) >>= f = 
                 let RevTuple (c,b1) = f a in RevTuple (c,b `mappend` b1)
```

Comment: That is not good enough since every time when I want to use `RevTuple` I have to use the type constructor and `totuple`.

Comment: @EarthEngine Hope, later we could use types: `type RevTuple b a = (a,b)` in this situation

Comment: You can have such a definition already. The problem is just that you can not say `instance Monoid b => Monad (RevTuple b)` in this case.

Comment: @EarthEngine Having to use the `RevTuple` constructor is technically no worse than having to use the `(,)` constructor. It only feels worse because it's a longer name.

Comment: Once I looked at those `newtype`s in `Data.Monoid` I realized that this is the normal thing happened in Haskell. So I mark this as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. It's crucial for `Monad` to be polymorphic in its parameter, so if a particular monadish thing only makes sense for monoids, it's not a monad.

For example, `return :: Monad m => a -> m a`. There's no way you can add an extra constraint to the signature of `return`.

Comment: Please refer to my update. The point is that I want to make the `Monad` instance act on the `a` of `(,) a b`, rather than `b`.

Comment: That is in every sense equivalent to the existing `Monad` instance, only with the order flipped. Is there any reason you can't use the existing instance and flip the order of the product when you need it the other way around?

Comment: @kqr Usually it is possible to flip the order before use. However I just want to know in general can I do this? How can I do so? I found some other cases that this might be useful. Also, I think repeatedly calling `flip` is still repeating myself.

Comment: Ah, then the `newtype` solution of @wit is the only one I know.